# Android: try to save id of the row in variable and make intent

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

On first activity user creates an object(A) after that Id + name of object(A) are saving in SQLite. When it saved user need to be forwarded to another activity but that activity need to have Id of object(A) which was created before. After that user will make some items insides the (object A). And when we go main activity and see list of objects(A) after pushing on item user will see all objects(B) which related to choosen object(A).

My code is

```
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    Thread thread;

    Button btnConfirmItemList;
    EditText etName;

    DBHelper dbHelper;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unit_list_item);

        btnConfirmItemList = findViewById(R.id.add_list_btn_confirm);
        btnConfirmItemList.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        thread = new Thread(this, "Поток для примера");
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Создан второй поток " + thread);
        thread.start(); // Запускаем поток


    }


    @Override
    public List<ListModel> addList(int id, String listName) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " ------ Второй поток запущен ------ ");

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();    
            String name = etName.getText().toString();    
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();    
            if(btnConfirmItemList.isEnabled()){
                cv.put("name", name);

                long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
            }

            dbHelper.close();

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " ------ Второй поток прерван ------ ");
        }

    }


    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");

            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "name text,"
                    + "email text" + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        public int getItemIdByPosition() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, 
 null);
            if (c.moveToLast()) {

                int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex));

                int idIndex = idColIndex;
                return idIndex ;
            } else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Id didnt selected");
            c.close();

            int idIndexx = idIndex;
            return idColIndex;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How to get id of created row in table a and using that id make some rows in another table which will related to id from table a

Comment: Your question is so vague. To clarify.. In activity1 you have a list, then when the user creates new object they are redirected to activity2 where the object they created are displayed. When they return back to activity1 the object created is displayed in the list and when user click on a item inside (activity1) of the list they are redirected to activity2 where object are displayed???

Comment: @H.Brooks im sorry:( No. Think like it is list of cart in online store. Activity1 includes list of carts. Activity2 shows what items each cart include

Comment: Ok so you already have the id of the row in your first activity and now you are asking how to get that id in the next?

Comment: @H.Brooks yes sir

Comment: You can do `intent.putextra`